# Joi custom .or() message

Tags: node.js, typescript, joi

I'm trying to customize an .or() function message on Joi, like this:

[image: Joi schema]

The Joi default message is this one:

> Validation Error: "value" must contain at least one of [optionOne, optionTwo]

I want it to be like this:

> Please, select one of the options

I tried using .message and .messages functions and also .error, but these don't work for me.

Are there another options to customize an .or() error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.messages()` is the right way to go, but the trick is finding the relevant message key. We can have a look in Joi's [list of errors](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#list-of-errors) for something that matches.

The one we're after is [`object.missing`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#objectmissing).

> The OR or XOR condition between the properties you specified was not satisfied in that object, none of them were set.

Therefore your schema could look something like this:

```js
Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.string()
})
    .or('a', 'b')
    .messages({
        'object.missing': 'Please, select one of the options'
    })
```